# Transfer Permission from one folder to another

Tags: opentext

I have a folder in Live link (open text) which has permission for certain people . I want to create another folder in another place with same permissions as this folder . How can i transfer all the permission without having to add them individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve it. This is how I do it.

As I'm not an admin , I cannot create a group and add users to it .

1. So I create a folder, give petrmission to users manually and apply changes to affect all the files and folders inside it.
2. Now I create a folder(Lets say 'A') inside that folder and so that the users have same permission as parent Folder.
3. Now I move this Folder A to the location a want and the permission is inherited so I dont have to add users again.

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the NodeRights the same as the source node.

```
           dmClient.SetNodeRights(ref dmOTAuth, NODEID, dmClient.GetNodeRights(ref dmOTAuth, SOURCENODEID));
```

Or Better yet just create the noderights and set them to the correct folder.